# sodapy (Socrata) connection gaierror

Tags: python-2.7, socrata

I'm trying to make API calls on the SFPD dataset, available online (https://data.sfgov.org/Public-Safety/SFPD-Incidents-from-1-January-2003/tmnf-yvry) with the SodaPy library (https://github.com/xmunoz/sodapy). I just want to get the json data.

I've followed the example on GitHub as best as I can, but it's just not working. Here's the code:

---

```
from sodapy import Socrata

client = Socrata(api_endpoint, app_token)

dataset_id = 'tmnf-yvry'

data = client.get(dataset_id, limit=2)
```

---

Despite these attempts, I keep getting the following error:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(8, 'nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))
```

---

Any clues on how to work through this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using credentials, etc, it needs to look something like this:

```
from sodapy import Socrata

cl = Socrata('data.colorado.gov','YOUR API KEY', username = 'YOUR USERNAME/EMAIL', password = 'YOUR PASSWORD')

then something like:
zx = cl.get('4eit-nuxn', limit=10, content_type='JSON', offset=0)
```

then deal with what is there in zx.  The above data is corporations in Colorado...  to call data by fields you can try this for a down and dirty approach:

```
for i in range(len(zx)):
    print string.capwords(zx[i]["entityname"]), string.capwords(zx[i]["principalcity"])
```

In my case, at the end of processing I needed to explicitly set the var (zx, here) to None, then close the connection.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
from sodapy import Socrata

client = Socrata('data.sfgov.org', None)

dataset_id = 'tmnf-yvry'

data = client.get(dataset_id, limit=2)
print data
{"stdout":"[{u'category': u'ASSAULT', u'dayofweek': u'Wednesday', u'incidntnum': u'050436712', u'time': u'04:00', u'descript': u'BATTERY', u'pddistrict': u'MISSION', u'y': u'37.7608878061245', u'location': {u'latitude': u'37.7608878061245', u'needs_recoding': False, u'human_address': u'{\"address\":\"\",\"city\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"zip\":\"\"}', u'longitude': u'-122.435002864271'}, u'address': u'18TH ST / CASTRO ST', u'date': u'2005-04-20T00:00:00', u'x': u'-122.435002864271', u'resolution': u'NONE', u'pdid': u'5043671204134'}, {u'category': u'LARCENY/THEFT', u'dayofweek': u'Sunday', u'incidntnum': u'080049078', u'time': u'18:00', u'descript': u'GRAND THEFT FROM A BUILDING', u'pddistrict': u'PARK', u'y': u'37.7622550270122', u'location': {u'latitude': u'37.7622550270122', u'needs_recoding': False, u'human_address': u'{\"address\":\"\",\"city\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"zip\":\"\"}', u'longitude': u'-122.446837820235'}, u'address': u'1100 Block of CLAYTON ST', u'date': u'2008-01-13T00:00:00', u'x': u'-122.446837820235', u'resolution': u'NONE', u'pdid': u'8004907806304'}]
```